# How can i improve the default layout template for my asp.net mvc 3 web application?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i need to improve the following in the default layout template for my asp.net mvc3 web application. part of the layout template looks as follow:-

```
<div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Statistics", "Index", "Statistics")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
```

What i am trying to do is :-

1. How i can change the colour of the currently selected `<li>...</li>` which is inside the  `<ul id="menu">.` . which can help the users to recognize the web pages there are currently viewing.
2. How i can add a sub menu which will be shown automatically when the user moves the mouse over a specific `<li></li>.`
   BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the use of a different menu, there are lots out there!
Check this [link](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/03/jquery-menu-plugins.html) in order to find some `JQuery` menus.

Oh, btw, in your second question, what you need is a JQuery function called `hover()` ([learn](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) how to use it), but dont worry, thats also implemented in those menus, just get one of those and adapt it to your needs.

Hope it helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="current">Home</li>
<ul>

<style>
  .current{background:#000;}
</style>
```

For Drop-down menu go here: http://www.cssnewbie.com/easy-css-dropdown-menus/.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multi-level sitemap with [MVCSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider). Here's a nice [tutorial](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/) to get You started. It generates menu using display templates, which You can easly style and change.

If You prefer to create menu manually and want to style currently selected menu item then follow this tutorial: [Create active menu item in MVC3](http://derekreynolds.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/create-activecurrent-menu-item-in-mvc3/)

Last thing is how to style/animate Your menu. There is a plethora of avaiable jQuery plugins out there like [14 easy to implement drop down menu solutions](http://webdesignledger.com/resources/14-easy-to-implement-drop-down-menu-solutions).

I personaly really like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) and it's [components](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).